# How to change the radial gradient for oval shape?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, flash-cs5, photoshop-cs4, photoshop-cs3

I have drawn a circle and applied radial gradient. fine.  But when i changed the dimension to oval, the radial gradient is not changing.  check the below screen - [image: a busy cat]

Comment: Try:Before resizing it, flatten the layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your shape to a smart object first, then resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Circle shape (ellipse tool), then apply "Gradient overlay" Layer style to it. In gradient overlay , make sure that "Align with Layer" is checked.
Now you can transform the circle to any shape, the gradient will adjust accordingly.